# Black screen when installing ATI Drivers on Netbook

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

I just installed Lubuntu on my Aspire One 725. It has a Radeon 7290 HD. I already tryied to install the drivers but after rebooting, i can only log in via terminal, there's no graphic interface anymore.

I fixed it by uninstalling fgrlx.

So my question is: Is there a proper way to install the ati drivers on my netbook, without getting the login black screen? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

which driver have you tried to install? catalyst or catalyst-legacy? I think your card needs the catalyst-legacy driver which currently does not support xorg 1.13!
To find out which version of Xorg your using, open a terminal window and
type Xorg -version.
If you have xorg 1.13 you can try downgrade to xorg 1.12 or wait until AMD updates the catalyst-legacy driver to support xorg 1.13.

But anyway why do you need the driver?
Afaik lubuntu doesn´t need 3-D support, the opensource-driver should work well...